# FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Invalid access_token, error code 43 ]

Tags: android, firebase, facebook-login

I am receiving this error in my application while trying to login using facebook with Firebase.
I did research the error and all suggestions were to check firebase and ensure that the AppId and AppSecret are copied correctly as well as in the android app. Do you have any other recommendations to check because i have no clue why i have this error. Noting that i tried creating a new facebook app and it worked perfectly